# Javascript Constructor inside a function

Tags: javascript, constructor

When I try to place the following codes inside a function and call it, I get error
Uncaught TypeError: Crypt is not a constructor
 What is wrong?

```js
var Crypt = new Crypt();  // constructor  
  
/*** encrypt */  

usertext = 'test'
var ciphertext = Crypt.AES.encrypt(usertext);  
// XluzvcUwZFU=3MD2vMz8PHySPJlKZiWjJg==1Gv6n6Tv8azr  
  
/*** decrypt */  
var plaintext  = Crypt.AES.decrypt(ciphertext);  





  console.log(ciphertext)
  console.log(plaintext)
```

Comment: It doesn't appear you've created the `Crypt` class

Comment: Where is Crypto defined?  It is not a native Constructor in the browser as far as I am aware, so are you adding it with a library or writing your own implementation somewhere?

Comment: is it node module crypto-js?

Comment: You are creating a variable `Crypt` with the same name as a mystery function `Crypt` whose definition isn't shown. So given that in the code shown there is no other definition of `Crypt` your code is equivalent to saying `var Crypt = undefined; Crypt = new undefined()`, and obviously `undefined` is not a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The variable Crypt is being declared in the function and is therefore trying to use itself (an undefined value) as the constructer for the new keyword.
Try this in your function
    var Crypt = new window.Crypt();  // the constructor in the global scope